# How to start page numbering, at the first page, in arabic, and continue till the end of the document?

Tags: page-numbering

I'm using the book class to write a thesis.
I would like the page numbering to start at the first page.
So the TOC looks like

```
1,3,5
```

wheter than

```
i, 1, 3
```

I have
[image]
from

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

    \frontmatter  

        \tableofcontents

    \mainmatter  

        \chapter{main}

    \begin{appendices}

        \chapter{appendix}

    \end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: changing the number is almost the only thing `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` do so you could just not use `\frontmatter`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't issue `\frontmatter` at all, since it's technically not needed if you want to start with `\arabic` numbering. As such, `\mainmatter` also become superfluous. Your document would therefore have the following structure:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{main}

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{appendix}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```